# IE javascript bookmarklet PDF link not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, bookmarklet

Create a simple bookmarklet

javascript:(function(){alert('test');})();

Opened a web page (ex wikipedia), and clicked on the bookmarklet, alert box was shown.

Then opened http://www.adobe.com/enterprise/accessibility/pdfs/acro6_pg_ue.pdf in IE.

Now the bookmarklet is not working. Nothing happens. But simple HTTP link bookmarks work.

I have tried in IE10 and IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF documents are hosted in an ActiveX control in MSIE browsers.

bookmarklets or scripted extensions will not work on ActiveX hosted content... never, never, never.

Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons> locate your installed PDF reader ActiveX control and disable it...

close and restart IE for the full changes to take affect.

navigate to your adobe test page...

expected... nothing or a blank new tab is displayed... the PDF reader ActiveX control is disabled...

in gecko and webkit browsers the Netscape plugins mode is used... chromium has their own PDF document plugin.... equally users of those userAgents can also disable their plugins (for security reasons).

Regards.